# Using CDN, how to set the correct custom plugin path?

Tags: javascript, java, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I'm new in CKEditor, and for the first time I'm trying to make a plugin. I'm trying to create a simple button as shown [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample).

I'm encountering the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "timestamp" was not found at "/WEB-INF/recursos/javascript/plugins/timestamp/plugin.js?t=H0CF".
    at window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:234)
    at h (ckeditor.js:230)
    at Array.n (ckeditor.js:230)
    at q (ckeditor.js:230)
    at HTMLScriptElement.CKEDITOR.env.ie.f.$.onerror (ckeditor.js:231)
```

Here's my "plugin.js" code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('timestamp',
{
    icons : 'timestamp',
    init : function(editor)
    {
        editor.addCommand('insertTimestamp',
        {
            exec : function(editor)
            {
                var now = new Date();
                editor.insertHtml('The current date and time is: <em>' + now.toString() + '</em>');
            }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton('Timestamp',
        {
            label : 'Insert Timestamp',
            command : 'insertTimestamp',
            toolbar : 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

And my default JavaScript code ("codigo.js"):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'timestamp', '/WEB-INF/recursos/javascript/plugins/timestamp/' , 'plugin.js' );

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'area-paragrafo', 
    {
        extraPlugins: 'timestamp'
    });
});
```

I'm using Java with Tomcat (and Eclipse IDE), and my directory structures are as follow:

[image]

I already tried to set the following path:

```
plugins/timestamp/
```

But this is giving me:

```
Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "timestamp" was not found at "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full-all/plugins/timestamp/plugin.js?t=H0CF".
```

I also tried the following path:

```
/plugins/timestamp/
```

And:

```
Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "timestamp" was not found at "/plugins/timestamp/plugin.js?t=H0CF".
```

My HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Page</title>

        <!-- JQuery. -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- MY FILES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/estilos.css}" />
        <script th:src="@{/js/codigo.js}"></script>

        <!-- CKEDITOR -->
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="papel-simples">

            <!-- CONTENT -->
            <textarea th:text="${paragrafo}" id="area-paragrafo"></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me, please? Thanks in advance.